# Proving Completeness in First Order Logic.

Tags: logic

If $S$ is a symbol set and $\Phi$ is a set of $S$-sentences, we let $\Phi^\vDash$ be the set of $S$-sentences which are consequences of $\Phi$. A mathematical proof of an $S$-sentence $\phi$ from the axioms in $\Phi$ shows that $\phi$ belongs to $\Phi^\vDash$. How can you show that the theory $\Phi^\vDash$ is complete, that is, for every sentence $\phi$ we have either $\Phi \vDash \phi$ or $\Phi \vDash \neg \phi$.

How does one go about in doing this? Should I show that $\Phi$ is consistent?

Comment: No, consistency does not imply completeness.

Comment: It is not true that every theory is complete. You need to provide some more information.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assume that the theory $\Phi$ is consistent: otherwise, it can prove everything and so it will be complete in an "uninteresting" sense.

But consistency is not enough.

The well known Godel's Incompleteness Theorem shows that there are consistent first-order theories that are not complete.